# C++ List destructor called after every use of List's method

Tags: c++, list, destructor

This is a follow up to a question I asked earlier today regarding the appropriation of directly calling a class' destructor.

I'm creating my own List for an assignment. I have overloaded the assignment, square brackets, in and out stream operators and have the basic adding, removing and printing to screen functionality.

My next step is to have the List delete and release the memory of all of its nodes, which I am having trouble with.

I have the List write to the screen its current state after performing its operations, as follows:

```
void main()
{
    // Create instance of list
    List aList(true);
    List bList(true);
    aList.Add(1);
    aList.Add(2);
    bList.Add(2);
    cout << "aList: " << aList;
    cout << "bList: " << bList;
    aList = bList;
    cout << "aList: " << aList;
    cout << "bList: " << bList;
    aList.Add(3);
    cout << "aList: " << aList;
    cout << "bList: " << bList;
    int i = 0; cin >> i;
}
```

Here is my overloaded out stream:

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, List theList)
{
    stream << "There are " << theList._totalNodes << " nodes in the list." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < theList._totalNodes; i++)
    {
        stream << "Node #" << i << " holds the data: " << theList[i] << endl;
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Looking at the command prompt window after this is used "Destructor called" is also printed underneath it.

The List destructor:

```
List::~List()
{
    cout << "Destructor called" << endl;
//  List::Destroy();
}
```

The overloaded assignment operator also seems to call the destructor, which doesn't surprise me. However, the others do.

```
List &List::operator=(List &aList)
{
    // Make sure not the same object trying to be copied
    if(this != &aList)
    {
        // Perform deep copy
        // Delete old pointers in redundant list, only if they exist already
        if(_head)
        {
            delete _head, _tail, _current, _del;
            _totalNodes = 0; // Reset total nodes
        }
        // Now set new pointers copied from other list
        _head = NULL;
        _tail = _head;
        _current = _head;
        _del = _head;
        // Now loop through all nodes in other list and copy them to this
        // Reset pointer in other list
        aList.Reset();
        for(int i = 0; i < aList._totalNodes; i++)
        {
            Add(aList.Current()->_data);
            aList.Next();
        }
        // Reset other list's pointer
        aList.Reset();
        Reset(); // Reset our pointer
    }
    return *this; // Return for multi assignment
}
```

I also have the destructor to a List write "Destructor called" when it's called and noticed that it is called after every use of one of its methods.

Why is this? I assumed the destructor is called when the object is no longer needed, i.e. deleted.

Furthermore, when stepping through my code I have noticed that when a pointer is deleted the memory address it is pointing to isn't being nullified. Do I have to manually NULL a pointer after it is deleted?

Comment: Please show the code of your list class, and the output your program produces.

Comment: You'd have to post the method code.

Comment: Without seeing the definition of some of these methods, it's hard to make an informed comment...

Comment: `delete _head, _tail, _current, _del;` only `delete`s `_head`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you took your List by value- that is, you copied it. You need to take it by const reference- that is,

`ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, const List& theList)`

Furthermore, your assignment operator should take a const reference, not a non-const ref.

I also don't think that this

`delete _head, _tail, _current, _del;`

does what you think it does. It just deletes `_del` and none of the others.

You should use a recursively self-owning design, where each node deletes the next one in the chain. Edit: As this was unclear, I'm going to post a brief sample.

```
template<typename T> struct Node {
    Node(const T& arg, Node* prev) : t(arg), previous(prev) {}
    T t;
    std::auto_ptr<Node<T>> next;
    Node<T>* previous;
};
template<typename T> class List {
    std::auto_ptr<Node<T>> head;
    Node<T>* tail;
public:
    List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) {}
    void clear() { head = tail = NULL; } // Notice how simple this is
    void push_back() {
        push_back(T());
    }
    void push_back(const T& t) {
        if (tail) {
            tail = (tail->next = new Node<T>(t, tail)).get();
            return;
        }
        tail = (head = new Node<T>(t, NULL)).get();
    }
    void pop_back() {
        tail = tail->previous;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }
    void pop_front() {
        head = head->next;
    }
    List<T>& operator=(const List& ref) {
        clear(); // Clear the existing list
        // Copy. Gonna leave this part to you.
    }
};
```

Notice how I never deleted anything- `std::auto_ptr` did everything for me, and manipulating the list and it's nodes became much easier, because `std::auto_ptr` manages all of the memory involved. This list doesn't even need a custom destructor.

I suggest that you read up heavily on `std::auto_ptr`, it has some surprises in it's interface, like the "copy" constructor and assignment operator actually move, that you are going to want to know about before using the class. I wish I could start using `std::unique_ptr` instead all of the time, which would make life so much easier.

Comment: I originally had the assignment op. take a const but took it out as I assume const prevents the passed list from being changed and I need it changed as I reset its _current pointer from within another List.

Comment: Also thanks for the answer to my question, it has solved the multiple destructor call.

Comment: @Lee: You can use `mutable` for that kind of situation. C++ recognizes that `const` is not always best expressed as a literal bitwise `const`.

Comment: @DeadMG: I agree with your description of `mutable`, but this isn't one of these situations.  The `List` class simply needs to be redesigned to not contain iterator-like state!

Comment: So that would mean to have a method within each node to delete the next? The reason mine is structured in this way is due to my lecture notes which have such List methods. Maybe it is done in this way for ease of understanding for students? I'm not really sure. I'll have a crack at the design you've recommended.

Comment: @Lee: What does deleting nodes have to do with copying?  If you take a look at e.g. the STL `std::list`, you'll see that it provides member functions `begin()` and `end()`, which return an `iterator` object, which knows how to traverse its parent's internal data structure.  That way, you separate the state required for storing the list from the state required to iterate over the list.

Comment: Oh, I am referring to DeadMG's last part of his answer. Those are great points, I'll be sure to look over them. However, for this assignment I think understanding the fundamental theory behind dynamic data structures is key, rather than efficiency and likeness with the already existing Lists. Thank you all for comments, I have learned a deal.

Comment: @Lee: No, the idea is that when you delete a Node, it deletes the next node. I will post a brief code sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot DeadMG. That's some nice code, however using previous implies doubly linked lists, right? At the moment I'm working with only singly linked lists. Would this render nodes deleting other nodes impossible?

Comment: @Lee: No- the magic of the design is in the `std::auto_ptr`. I made it doubly linked to simplify some implementation details, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator <<` overload is taking a `List` *by-value*.  This requires a copy to be made (to create the local variable), and this local copy is destructed at the end of the overload function.  This is why you're seeing the destructor being called over and over again.

Consider changing your overload to take a `const List &` instead.  The `&` means that it's passed-by-reference, so no copy is made.  The `const` means that the function guarantees not to alter the object.

Comment: I understand references and constants, but am I incorrect in thinking that I need an non-constant List passed as I alter the _current pointer in one List from another?

Comment: @Lee: You should be writing your class in such a way that you don't need to modify the state of one list in order to simply copy it!

Comment: Yes, that would be preferred. Back to the drawing board on that one :)